# NoNodeAvailableException when using RestHighLevelClient 6.8.10

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

The application had been using TCP client in the past. Due to a lot of instability in the elastic search connection, implemented Rest High Level Client to establish connection between application and ES cluster. The port used is 9300.

At times, when ES failure happens, following error occurs and we restart the elastic search to unblock the operations.

Java ElasticSearch None of the configured nodes are available
`"message":"failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}`

Thought the port 9300 which is dedicated for TCP is causing the issue and updated the port to 9200 but no luck. This time the application couldn't connect to ES at all with the same exception shown above.

ES Rest Client version used is 6.8.10 and the elastic search version running on the server is the same 6.8.10.

Comment: Can you please provide sample code which you written for connection? also, are you able to access elasticsearch using curl or from browser ?

Comment: `@Configuration
public class ConfigElasticSearchRestClient {

    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes}")
    String elasticHost;

    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient client() {
        return new RestHighLevelClient( RestClient.builder( HttpHost.create(elasticHost)));
    }

}`

cluster-nodes: ${elasticsearch-client:localhost}:${elasticsearch-port:9300}
Client gets patched from configmaps at runtime